# ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Weekday Name'

Tags: python, seaborn, valueerror

I want to plot this data https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenfly/opsd/master/opsd_germany_daily.csv

But I have an error

> ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Weekday Name'

How can I fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11, 4)})

font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 15}

matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
opsd_daily = pd.read_csv('opsd_germany_daily.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
sns.boxplot(data=opsd_daily, x='Weekday Name', y='Consumption');
```

FYI

Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no column called `Weekday Name` in your input:

```
Date,Consumption,Wind,Solar,Wind+Solar
2006-01-01,1069.1840000000002,,,
2006-01-02,1380.5210000000002,,,
2006-01-03,1442.5330000000001,,,
```

You'll need to convert it yourself:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize": (11, 4)})
font = {"family": "normal", "weight": "bold", "size": 15}
matplotlib.rc("font", **font)

csv = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenfly/opsd/master/opsd_germany_daily.csv"
# pandas can read from remote URL
opsd_daily = pd.read_csv(csv)

# convert the `Date` column
opsd_daily["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(opsd_daily["Date"])

# Get the `Weekday Name` column
opsd_daily["Weekday Name"] = opsd_daily["Date"].dt.day_name()

sns.boxplot(data=opsd_daily, x="Weekday Name", y="Consumption")
```

Which produces:

[image: Generated boxplot]